# Facebook In-App Browser Cannot Launch iTunes Link

Tags: ios, facebook, browser, app-store, mobile-safari

When iOS Facebook's in-app browser loads my web page, I have a link there to "Download App Now" which links to the App Store Page, i.e.
https://itunes.apple.com/my/app/XXXXX/12345678?ls=1&mt=8

If this is loaded in Safari, it launches the corresponding app page in App Store correctly and users can instantly download the app.

However, if launched within Facebook's in-app browser, the browser shows a warning: "Leave Facbook? This web page is trying to open an app outside of Facebook. Are you sure you want to open it?"

If I click "Open App", nothing happens. I've tried changing the link using href, onclick, target=_blank and nothing works, basically FB app just failed to launch the external app page.

Is this a bug with Facebook app? I need the open app link feature as I'm showing a website and wish to redirect mobile users to download the app instead.

I'm using iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 8.1, and the latest Facebook app. I tried it in my iPad 4 iOS 7, same problem too.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is a bug and you find it on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks, I tried searching there but couldn't find the exact report pertaining to this problem. Can you please point me to the right post? The bugs reported there also appear to be pertaining to API / SDK, but this problem is pertaining to their app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by WizKid, this is/was a [known problem](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/601354783338830/). It should be fixed with the most recent version of the app.

Comment: Thank you Roemer, I just tested the latest Facebook update and it has been fixed.